# IndexPath and indexPath don't work

Tags: swift, xcode, uialertview

I'm trying to add an AlertView when a Club somebody tries to delete a club in my app.

```swift
func createAlert() {
            let sheet = UIAlertController(title: "Diesen Verein löschen?", message: "Wollen Sie diesen Verein für immer löschen?", preferredStyle:.alert)
            present(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
            let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Löschen", style: .default , handler: { (action) in
                self.deleteClub(at: IndexPath)
            })
            let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }
```

But I can't do this because the line with self.deleteClub(at: IndexPath) throws an error. I can't do this with indexPath either.
I searched long for the problem but I couldn't find anything.

That is my deleteClub Function:

```swift
  func deleteClub(at indexPath: IndexPath){
            let club = clubs[indexPath.row]

            guard let managedContext = club.managedObjectContext else {
                return
            }
            managedContext.delete(club)

            do {
                try managedContext.save()

                clubs.remove(at: indexPath.row)

                tableViewClub.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            } catch {
                print("Could not delete")

                tableViewClub.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        }
```

Comment: You mention it throwing an error... where is the error? What does it say?

Comment: Where are you getting the indexPath from? In your code it just seems to appear out of thin air. Where is it created?

Comment: Also the actions aren't added to the UIAlertController

Comment: IndexPath is undeclared variable in this function !

Comment: @Somebody  I added it to the question

Comment: @Fogmeister I added it to the question

Comment: @Teetz What do you exactly mean?

Comment: @Fogmeister One time: Cannot convert value of type 'IndexPath.Type' to expected argument type 'IndexPath The other time: use of unresolved Identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the definition of your `createAlert` method like so:

```
func createAlert(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let sheet = UIAlertController(title: "Diesen Verein löschen?", message: "Wollen Sie diesen Verein für immer löschen?", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Löschen", style: .destructive , handler: { (action) in
        self.deleteClub(at: indexPath)
    })
    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    sheet.add(action1)
    sheet.add(action2)
    present(sheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

to a) add the actions to the alert and b) call `self.deleteClub(at: indexPath)` (note using the lowercase `indexPath` parameter instead of the uppercase `IndexPath` type name) from the "Löschen" action.

Of course you'll then have to pass the indexPath of the table or collection cell to this method.

Comment: Thank you very very much, that worked fine. Just one problem: If I want to delete a club there is a Thread 1 Sigabrt error. Do you know where that could come from?

Comment: If my answer helped, please click the checkmark to accept it. As to your sigabrt crash: no, not without knowing where exactly it occurs. Please create a new question for this, with enough details for others to understand and/or reproduce the error.

Comment: Okey, I accepted it. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to add `.row` after indexPath (`indexPath.row`)?